# How to loop through opening and ending strings in a file bash?

Tags: bash, shell, awk, scripting, grep

I am writing an shell script to loop through strings and echo the matches if the word is present in that testcase.

I have an file which looks like

```
/*
  some build info #which are not matter of interest
*/
Test: TestCase_one
.
.
   output of that testcase 
   #TestCase_one name will not be present in btw
.
.
TestCase_one passed 
Test: TestCase_two
.
.
   output of that testcase
.
.
   TestCase_two passed 
   many testcases in this pattern
/*
   some thread info
*/
```

in that above file i want to check for a particular word for each 
testcase and echo matches if that word is present, for this i want to loop through file for each testcase and then move step by step to the end of the file

Is there an way to start grepping for a word in between TestCase_one and TestCase_one Passed and so on?

I have no background in shell scripting, any suggestions or man pages to achieve this would be helpful to me.

expected output should look like

```
TestCase_one
No matches
TestCase_TWo
.
.
  matched lines
.
.
```

thanks in advance

Comment: can awk be used to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume what you what is the following:

Between 'Test: Testcase' and 'TestCase_.*passed' search for string 'foo'. Print the matching lines if there is a match.

Could you simply do:

```
cat bigfile | grep -E '(foo|^Test: TestCase)'
```

It would not match your expected output perfectly (e.g. "No matches" will not be printed - there will just not be any matches), but it is pretty close and very simple.

If you do not want all testcases but want to look at a single one then this might work for you:

```
cat file |
  perl -ne '/^Test: Testcase start/ .. /Test case end/ and /foo/ and print'
```

It will search for `foo` but only between `Test: Testcase start` and `Test case end`. If you want to include the start line in the output, use:

```
cat file |
  perl -ne '/^Test: Testcase start/ .. /Test case end/ and /^Test: Testcase start|foo/ and print'
```

Comment: **cat trinity.log | grep -E '(LEAK|^Test: SYNC_LOST_TestCase)'** it is printing all the foo in the file, did i do something wrong? the reason i want loop through is the presence of foo in some testcases is not problem and in some it is an error for this i want to check if there is an foo in the testcases of interest. thank you the answer

Comment: Maybe you should take a look at agrep, esp. its -d option, which might be used here e.g. as agrep -d '^Test: ' 'b#w' FILE. Do read its manpage though, esp. on the form of the search pattern.

Comment: @Roadowl that looks promising, but  agrep doesn't exist in my project this script will be used by many developers in this project(if i am able to finish this) i don't think they all want to install agrep for the tiny purpose this script serves thank you!

Comment: @kuchu Do all the start lines start with "Test: SYNC_LOST_TestCase"? If not, then change that to what every start line of testcases start with.

Comment: Do you have csplit(1)? You might split the file into smaller files, each with one record, then grep these files.  E.g. csplit --prefix='test-' --suffix-format='%06d' $FILE '/^Test: /' '{*}'

Comment: @Roadowl i have csplit, but how to set the limits in this? prefix and suffix are for the name of the file right if i am not misunderstood, **csplit --prefix='test-' --suffix-format='%06d' trinity.log '/^TestCase: /' '{*}'** i have used this then i got everything in another file name test-00000

Comment: When I run the command on your file like I said, csplit --prefix='test-' --suffix-format='%06d' $FILE '/^Test: /' '{*}' then I get three files, test-000000 (58 bytes), test-000001 (125 bytes) and test-000002 (138 bytes). test-000000 is the stuff "some build info", and the other two are TestCase 1 and TestCase two, that you can now grep individually.

Comment: @Roadowl i tried it on the sample log file i provided, it just did what was requried, but in the original logfile if i apply the same csplit for this word "Test: " surprisingly it didn't work i have replaced Test: with kuchu: to see if that makes any change it copied the whole file into one. but does it need to have word Test: as the first letter in the line?? since in my logfile the Test: word comes after time stamps and  component name

Answer (score 0):

A while back I needed something like this, so I have this which might help you -

```
    #!/bin/bash

    checking_start=1 # flag for start of test case
    processing=0 # flag for processing a test case

    while IFS="" read -r p || [ -n "$p" ]; do # "p" is line in text file
        if [ $checking_start -eq 1 ]; then # checking for test case start
            mystartstr=`echo "$p" | grep Test: ` 
            if [ -z "$mystartstr" ]; then # if "mystartstr" is empty, continue
                echo "Non-related"
            else
                echo "Started processing.." # else set processing flag
                processing=1 # processing now true
                checking_start=0 # checking start of test case flag- false
            fi
        elif [ $processing -eq 1 ]; then  # if processing come here
            myendstr=`echo "$p" | grep TestCase_` # checking end of test case string
            if [ -z "$myendstr" ]; then # if end test case string empty, continue processing
                echo "Processing.." # This is where you will put your grep
            else
                echo "Ended processing.."  # Else end processing
                processing=0 # processing flag set as false
                checking_start=1 # start checking for new test case start
            fi
        else
            echo "No where.. Should never come here"
        fi
    done < sample.txt # Piping your text file here
```

The `sample.txt` I used is -

```
    /*
      some build info #which are not matter of interest
    */
    Test: TestCase_one
    .
    .
       output of that testcase
    .
    .
    .
    TestCase_one passed
    Test: TestCase_two
    .
    .
       output of that testcase
    .
    .
    TestCase_two passed
       many testcases in this pattern
    /*
       some thread info
    */
```

Comment: can you please explain what the above snippet does, i didn't get what this one in trying to do (I have just started with shell scripting) thanks for answer anyhow

Comment: @kuchu oh I will add comments then

Comment: @kuchu I added comments hope it helps.

Comment: I still didn't get how p knows where to start from (or do i need to make an array of testcases and assign them to p), does **grep "leak" trinity.log**  placed after echo processing grep between end and start of testcase? and in place of sample.txt  i kept **trinity.log**  or should it be **sample.txt |trinity.log**

only adding the grep line and file at the end, i have ended up in infinite loop printing grepped terms multiple times, can the myendstr be used to print the Testcase name like **echo -e ${myendstr}** followed by grep thing.

Comment: @kuchu The last line is the where I am feeding the file to the while loop and p starts from line 1 in the file and runs till it reaches last line. If your file is `trinity.log`, then replace `sample.txt` with it. `myendstr` is the condition indicating this test case has been processed. It should return empty unless it is the line like `TestCase_two passed`.

Comment: I am not sure if i am doing it right or not (i made only two changes to the code you have posted one is feeding the file another one is **grep -F '[LEAK]:' path/trinity.log;** after echo "Processing ..", but this is entering into infinite loop i gave it five minutes to stop but it was still running printing all the matches @ViKiG

Comment: @kuchu how many lines file is it? The sample.txt I used is working. I will paste the sample.txt for you in my answer.

Comment: In my program I have put the condition for `myendstr` as `grep TestCase_`. See if it is what you need. Similary, for `mystartstr` too, you have to check the condition required for text file `trinity.log`.

Comment: Also, you say you added a line below `echo Processing..` as `grep -F'[LEAK]:' path/trinity.log`. You need to change this line. You already have the line from `trinity.log` which is `$p` in the above program. If you want to grep a line, use `echo "$p" | grep someConditionString`

Comment: it was 5000 lines big and 14 TestCases in it , it will grow as more TestCases will be added in future, i am using **grep "_TestCase PASSED"** when i perform the above grep command on the log file i have exactly 14 hits for 14 different testcases, i have change **echo "$p" |grep -F '[LEAK]:' path/trinity.log;** don't know the reason why it is ending up in infinite loo.

Comment: In any case it should not go into infinite loop. If the file size is 5000 lines the program should come to halt. Remove, condition `|| [ -n "$p" ]` in `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

An awk version:

```
awk <test.log -v k='MATCHWORD' -e '
    $1=="Test:" { print n=t=$2; next }
    t && $0~k   { n=0; print }
    $1==t && n  { t=0; print "No matches" }
'
```

- `k` : variable containing word to match
- `t` : variable containing name of testcase
- `n` : variable indicating if word not yet found in this testcase
- `$1=="Test:"` : start of testcase?
- `t && $0~k` : in a testcase and line contains word?
- `$1==t && n` :  end of testcase and word not found?